# How to Flip a Double Linked List in java and put it into a new List

Tags: java

I wanted to flip a Double Linked List and put it into a new List. But I don't know how to solve the Problem. My Code looks like this and I think it makes sense, but it doesn't work at all.

*getPred = previous
getSucc = next*

```
    public DoublyLinkedList fliping()
    {
        DoublyLinkedList newList = new DoublyLinkedList();
        Element current = last;
        Element toInsert = newList.first;
        while(current != null)
        {
            current.disconnectPred();
            Element temp = current.getPred();
            Element temp2 = current.getPred().getPred();
            if(toInsert == newList.first)
            {
                temp.connectAsSucc(temp2);
                temp2.connectAsPred(temp);
                toInsert.connectAsSucc(temp);
                newList.size++;
            }
            if(temp2 == null)
            {
                temp.connectAsSucc(temp2);
                toInsert.connectAsSucc(temp);
                newList.size++;
            }
            temp.connectAsSucc(temp2);
            temp2.connectAsPred(temp);
            toInsert.connectAsSucc(temp);
            toInsert.connectAsPred(temp2);
            toInsert = toInsert.getSucc();
            current = current.getPred();
            newList.size++;
            size--;
        }
        return newList;
    }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Element.getPred()" because the return value of "Element.getPred()" is null
    at DoublyLinkedList.fliping(DoublyLinkedList.java:282)
    at Testumgebung.testDoublyLinkedList(Testumgebung.java:35)
    at Testumgebung.main(Testumgebung.java:7)
```

I tried to disconnect the last element and the second last element. Than i tried to connect them to each other and put them togeter, as the first and second element into the new List

Comment: What does `current.disconnectPred();` do?  You're calling it directly before the call to `getPred()`.

Comment: public void disconnectSucc()
    {
        if ( hasSucc() ) 
        {
            succ.pred = null;
            succ = null;
        }
    }

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "flip" ? reverse the order?

Comment: public void connectAsSucc( Element e)
    {
        disconnectSucc();
        succ = e;
        if ( e != null ) 
        {
            e.disconnectPred();
            e.pred = this;
        }
    }

Comment: I want to put the "old" List in reverse into the "new" List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `DoublyLinkedList` implements the interface `java.util.List` I would first ensure that you can copy it (e.g. with a copy-constructor that initializes it with any other `Collection` or `List` - don't implement the `clone` method, too much hassle with that!).

Then simply use the method `java.util.Collections.reverse(List<?>)` on a 1:1 copy of your original list.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answear, but i wanted to write a method for it and not use a import, to solve the problem

Comment: It is always recommendable to use existing methods instead of reinventing the wheel - especially if the methods are part of the standard Java SDK. If it is absolutely necessary that this is part of the class `DoublyLinkedList` you could use the described algorithm inside a method and just return the result. Or have at least a look at the code of the `reverse` method to get inspiration.

Comment: You still can have a look at the sourcecode of the method in the JDK, then implement it, and then start to optimize it for your implementation of the list - and btw. I did not downvote you...